# Can I schedule a workflow in CQ5?

Tags: workflow, aem

In CQ5, there is an option to schedule page activation on a particular date. I want to be able to do the same with a workflow — that I can initiate/queue it today, but it will only start executing its steps on a specified date.

Is this possible to implement this feature via a custom workflow step, using the Workflow API? Or is there another way this could be done, e.g. using Sling Events/Scheduling?

Comment: Hi OP, maybe you'd like to give more details on what you've already tried so that people are better able to help? — Have you checked the documentation on [extending workflows](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/workflows/wf-extending.html)? Are you working in Java, ECMAScript? What have you tried so far? Where specifically are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 2):

There's a process step called the AbsoluteTimeAutoAdvancer which reads a property named absoluteTime from the WorkflowData's MetaData. This is expected to be numeric long value which represents the activation time since Epoch in milliseconds.

The trick is to set this value in the metadata. I would suggest reading
[extending workflows](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/workflows/wf-extending.html) the section entitled *Saving Property Values in Workflow Metadata*